# ejb-jar.xml.unfiltered unable to be deleted

Tags: maven, ejb

In my ejb maven build, I often get this error :

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (default-ejb) on
>   project autocat-core: There was a problem creating the EJB archive:
>   File
>   C:\Users\ndx\Documents\workspaces\eclipse-javaee\autocat\autocat-core\target\classes\META-INF\ejb-jar.xml.unfiltered
>   unable to be deleted. -> [Help 1]

What can I do to get rid of it ?

**EDIT** Notice it also happens on our Windows continuous integration server, which only runs maven, and have no Eclipse installed **at all**.

Comment: Is any malicious software running? (virus/antivirus)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you run in such an obscure workspace location name if that is in your Continuous Integration server?

- Check whether you Continuous Integration server run more than 1 job but are using the same workspace?
- Check whether there is Windows ACL anomalies within the workspace: the user ndx supposed to be the one running the Maven build, I guess
- Check whether there is some Java process that still holds the file
- What Continuous Integration system runs?

  - Self built code?
  - Jenkins/Hudson?
  - Continuum?

Answer (score 1):

Your eclipse or other applications open it and lock.

Windows prevents to delete open files. So you have to close all applications before compile (your IDE, application server, etc).

Comment: Problem : it also happens on our integration server, on which there is only maven running ...

Comment: What is operation system  installed on your integration server?

Comment: Windows XP. **But**, as I clearly stated in answer, there is no process other than Maven using that file on that server.

Comment: To be sure check [openfiles command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490961.aspx)